# Sqllite nested sum statement is returning wrong value for not repeated records in the database

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get the sum of counted products in the database, when I am using a nested sum statement the results are wrong for one record that isn't repeated.
my code:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO COUNT_REPORT
                (
                PRODUCT_CODE, 
                BRANCH, 
                WAREHOUSE, 
                PRODUCT_NAME, 
                CURRENT_COUNT, 
                PREVIOUS_COUNT,
                DIFFERENCE,
                STATE,
                DATE,
                PRICE
                )
                    SELECT
                    PROD_CODE,
                    (SELECT UNVAN FROM BRANCHES WHERE SUBE_KODU = BRANCH_CODE), 
                    (SELECT DEPO_ISMI FROM WAREHOUSES WHERE DEPO_KODU = WARE_CODE),
                    (SELECT STOK_ADI FROM PRODUCT_DETAILS WHERE STOK_KODU = PROD_CODE),
                    (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM FINAL_DATA GROUP BY PROD_CODE),
                    PREVIOUS_COUNT,
                    DIFFERENCE,
                    STATE,
                    TASK_DATE,
                    PRICE
                    FROM FINAL_DATA
                    WHERE TASK_ID = ?
```

I tried to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY and another nested statement. I expected query to return the sum of quantity in repeated records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was doing a subquery in the same table twice, so instead of:

```
(SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM FINAL_DATA GROUP BY PROD_CODE)
```

I used:

```
SUM(QUANTITY)
```

it is working now as intended.